# Why do veins contain lower concentration of proteins as compared to arteries?

Tags: circulatory-system, lymphatic-system

[image: Question]

[image: Answer Key]

In Q 9.b, it is said that the blood in Y has lower concentration of proteins/amino acids as compared to the blood in X.

But why is it so?

The blood in Y should have more protein as the tissues may secrete some proteins into the blood as they flow like they would in case of lymph going through lymphatic vessels.

Comment: Well, that's sort of the issue, the tissue in the image isn't specified - is it gut, lung, liver, kidney? It's impossible to generalize a conclusion as we're not homogeneous colony organisms. Can you add detail at all about the specifics of the question?

Comment: The tissue isn't specified in the question

Comment: Well, I guess that's the answer then, "They don't, unless they do."

Comment: "In this image it is said that the blood in Y has lower concentration of proteins/amino acids as compared to the blood in X." - the image doesn't say this to me at all, is this a quote from someplace? What's the actual statement? I don't see how anyone can begin to approach a "why" without first clarifying what's being explained. Where did you encounter this image? Who is telling you about X and Y and what *precisely* do they say? Is it even intended to be true or just a prelude to asking some other question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> lower concentration of proteins/amino acids/fatty acids/other named nutrient

This answer key wants to allow an answer that the blood at Y has fewer nutrients than the blood at X because you should assume that some respiring tissue is taking up nutrients from the blood supply.

In my view, "proteins" does not fit on this list. Protein is not a "nutrient" at the cellular level. For some reason, the person who made this answer key included protein in the allowable list. Your question should not be "Why do veins contain lower concentration of proteins" but rather "Why does this answer key allow for 'protein' as a possible answer". Maybe they don't want to make a distinction between protein and amino acids for some reason; I disagree with them, but that's okay. Maybe some student made a good argument for protein in some specific tissue and they simply decided to include it in the answer key as close enough.

I would very very strongly **advise against using an answer key as a way to study** a topic, only to judge your potential answers to that question. Read the text that goes along with it, where the author has made a more intentional approach to the content. Reading the answer key is not a good shortcut.